# Detach a pointer from a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to release pointer from boost::shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525764/how-to-release-pointer-from-boostshared-ptr)

A function of my interface returns a pointer to an object. The user is supposed to take ownership of that object. I do not want to return a Boost.shared_ptr, because I do not want to force clients to use boost. Internally however, I would like to store the pointer in a shared_ptr to prevent memory leaks in case of exceptions etc. There seems to be no way to detach a pointer from a shared pointer. Any ideas here?

Comment: Is it an option to return a copy of the shared object and let the smart pointer clean-up the original?

Comment: Not really, the object is a videoframe in HD resolution, so copy is to expensive.

Comment: Note that C++11 has std::unique_ptr which can be used for temporarily storing the pointer and releasing it on return.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `release` function; `shared_ptr` doesn't have a release function.  [Per the Boost manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm):

> Q. Why doesn't shared_ptr provide a release() function?
>
> A. shared_ptr cannot give away ownership unless it's unique() because the other copy will still destroy the object.
>
> Consider:

```
shared_ptr<int> a(new int);
shared_ptr<int> b(a); // a.use_count() == b.use_count() == 2

int * p = a.release();

// Who owns p now? b will still call delete on it in its destructor.
```

> Furthermore, the pointer returned by release() would be difficult to deallocate reliably, as the source shared_ptr could have been created with a custom deleter.

Two options you might consider:

- You could use `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, which would require your users to use a C++ library implementation supporting TR1 *or* to use Boost; at least this would give them the option between the two.
- You could implement your own `boost::shared_ptr`-like shared pointer and use that on your external interfaces.

You might also look at the discussion at this question about [using boost::shared_ptr in a library's public interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335330/using-boostsharedptr-in-a-librarys-public-interface).

Comment: Ok, feared it might be something like that.

Comment: shared_ptr is a bit like const keyword, add it in one place and you have to use it everywhere

Comment: Readers: Scroll down: [Make your own deleter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5995770/321013)

Answer (score 27):

there's always a way :-)

There is indeed a reason why they don't provide a release() method, but it's not impossible to create one. Make your own deleter. Something on the line of (haven't actually compiled the code, but this is the general notion):

```
template <typename T>
class release_deleter{
public:
  release_deleter() : released_(new some_atomic_bool(false)){}
  void release() {released_->set(true);}
  void operator()(T* ptr){if(!released_->get()) delete ptr;}
private:
  shared_ptr<some_atomic_bool> released_;
}

..

shared_ptr<some_type> ptr(new some_type, release_deleter<some_type>());

..

release_deleter<some_type>* deleter = get_deleter<release_deleter<some_type>>(ptr);
deleter->release();
some_type* released_ptr = ptr.get();
```

Comment: Why is the private `released_` member a shared_ptr?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I did it as a regular bool and it suited my needs perfectly.

Comment: No reason. I hadn't actually looked into the code, but now I see that deleter is stored with the shared_count, so no additional sharing would be required.

Comment: Why `some_atomic_bool` instead of `bool`? Do you aim at some kind of MT safety?

Comment: Depending on how the releaser is used, the release operation may have to be atomic, though the example above isn't entirely up for the task. If the release() function is used from multiple threads, it will have to be atomic, and also indicate to the caller if ownership was obtained or not. A bool return value would do fine. Otherwise, there's a risk for double deletes or leaks.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with this more no-nonsense version that doesn't hardcode the delete action: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23866812/

Comment: @sehe Link is dead.

Answer (score 11):

> The user is supposed to take ownership of that object. I do not want to return a Boost.shared_ptr,

`shared_ptr` expresses *shared* ownership, and you want your interface to express *transfer* of ownership. `std::auto_ptr` would thus be more applicable here.

> Internally however, I would like to store the pointer in a shared_ptr to prevent memory leaks in case of exceptions

Again, `shared_ptr` may not be the best tool for that job. To prevent leaks in the case of exceptions, `scoped_ptr` or `auto_ptr` would be better suited.

Answer (score 6):

Use a `shared_ptr` to a `scoped_ptr` to the resource (`shared_ptr<scoped_ptr<Resource>>`).  That way you get `shared_ptr`'s reference counting, which will automatically destroy the resource if and only if it's still attached to the `scoped_ptr`.  But you can detach the `scoped_ptr` when you're ready to hand off ownership.

Comment: Clever, but now you have to change *p to **p every where. This shows a problem with the `shared_ptr` design.

Comment: @curiousguy: How often do you use `*` on a smart pointer?  Usually you use `->`, which has chaining semantics.  And anyway, the exact same syntax wasn't required in the question, and this has the advantage of working exactly like the OP wanted.

Comment: "_How often do you use * on a smart pointer?_" I don't know. "_Usually you use ->, which has chaining semantics._" Clever, I forgot that. But I don't like the double indirection: since the lack of `release` is just a shortcoming of `shared_ptr` design, so I wouldn't want to change code that uses it just for this reason. I prefer to work around the arbitrary limitation by changing the deleter: that's an additional indirection too, but it doesn't affect code that uses the smart pointer. (But in reality I would rather write my own smart pointer without `shared_ptr` limitations.)

Comment: Very cool. This works around the problem with binding `std::unique_ptr` to an `std::function`.

Answer (score 2):

As James has well covered you can't really detach a shared pointer.

Do you need multiple owners internally, or are you transferring ownership from your class to the client? In that case a `std::auto_ptr` might fit the bill.

If you're worried about the surprising semantics of `std::auto_ptr`, you could hold it internally by `boost::scoped_ptr`, and detach it at the point you hand it out - leaving it up to the client to manually delete it or store it in their own smart pointer.

If you do have multiple owners on your side you could use an intrusive count. Internally you could then use `boost::intrusive__ptr`, but hand off the raw pointer at the interface. The client can then either manually work with ref counts, or store it in a `boost::intrusive_ptr` themselves (but you don't make them depend on it)