# boost::shared_ptr to void * and vice versa

Tags: c++, c, boost

I am developing an application in C, where I need to used a 3rd party C++ library. So, I am basically writing a wrapper around the C++ library to make it possible to call it from my application which is in pure C. Some of the methods in the library returns pointer of type `boost::shared_ptr`, which I need to cast to `void*` [for C] and then convert it back to `boost::shared_ptr` type to reuse it for further processing. I used the following ways to do the conversion:

To `void*` :

```
void * func1()
{
    //after the boost::shared_ptr is created
    return static_cast<void *> (SHARED_PTR.get())
}
```

From `void*` :

```
void func2(void * VOID_PTR) //VOID_PTR returned by func1
{
    boost::shared_ptr<T> SHARED_PTR = *(boost::shared_ptr <T> *)(VOID_PTR);
}
```

However, I am getting `SIGSEGV` in `func2`, which I believe is happening because the `shared_ptr` being deallocated because its ref-count getting 0.

I was looking for correct ways to do this conversion and suggestions from experts of the SO community.

Comment: Shouldn't the back-cast really be an initialization instead? Such as `boost::shared_ptr<T>(VOID_PTR)`?

Comment: No. Then you'd have two smart pointers both with responsibility to delete that pointer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "_Then you'd have two smart pointers_" I don't think you'd have anything: if you can't do `delete p;` how could you do `boost::shared_ptr<T>(p)`?

Answer (score 8):

Think about who owns the instance of T, and when.

I'm guessing you're getting a shared_ptr from your C++ library function, getting its value, then letting the shared_ptr go out of scope. When this happens, as you suggested, the managed object will be deleted.

To get around this, you will have to keep the original shared_ptr alive for the lifetime of your use of its managed object.

```
void* func1(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& sharedPtr)
{
    add_to_some_kind_of_persistent_storage(sharedPtr);
    return static_cast<void*>(sharedPtr.get());
}
```

You could also use a trick with a customer deleter object to effectively release the managed object from the shared_ptr, but this might not be safe if there are other instances of shared_ptr hanging around which manage the same object. See here: [Detach a pointer from a shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833356/detach-a-pointer-from-a-shared-ptr/5995770#5995770)

To pass it back in:

```
boost::shared_ptr<T> func2(void* voidPtr) //VOID_PTR returned by func1
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<T>(voidPtr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

nowadays that shared_ptr is part of the standard library

```
std::shared_ptr<type> ptr;
auto ptr1 = reinterpret_cast<void *>(&ptr); /* shared_ptr > void ptr */
auto ptr2 = * reinterpret_cast(std::shared_ptr<type>*)(ptr1); /* void ptr > shared_ptr */
```

Comment: Why do you use `reinterpret_cast` here?

Comment: auto ptr2 = * reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<type>*>(ptr1);

Answer (score 1):

What to do depends on what the C library does with the `void*` pointer. If it at some point is used as a `T*` then that's what you need to pass, as you're doing. To get back a `shared_ptr` you then need `T` to implement [`boost::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), and call its `shared_from_this` member function, i.e. `reinterpret_cast<T*>(void_ptr)->shared_from_this()`.