# Convert a shared_ptr to regular a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, shared-ptr

We have a function that returns a new allocated object as a output argument (ref to pointer).

```
MyFunc(MyObject*& obj)
{
    obj = new MyObject();
}
```

Which is called like so:

```
Object* obj;
MyFunc(obj);
```

Internally the function does quite a bit and uses `shared_ptr` for memory management.  When it is done, the object we would like to return is referenced by a `shared_ptr`.  I am struggling on how to return our new allocated object as a regular pointer.

We would like to continue to use `shared_ptr` internally to reduce risks, but it does not seem to make sense to return a `shared_ptr` as the caller takes complete ownership over the returned value (the called function or object no longer needs or keeps a reference to the returned data) and we want them to have flexibility.

Does anyone have any suggestions for allowing us to use `shared_ptr` internally but have a regular pointer interface?  Thanks

Comment: sounds like u should use a unique_ptr instead, then just return .get()

Comment: @AndersK. I don't want the caller to be required to use unique_ptr either.

Comment: Is it impossible to change the interface? Do you need to interface with C code or something? Why can't you just return a smart pointer, as in idiomatic C++? A reference to a pointer is horrible ugliness.

Comment: @denver if you are not sharing the variable then internally use a unique_ptr, once you want to pass the ownership to the caller via just do .release() to get the pointer

Comment: @AndersK. unique_ptr and .release would seem to be the ticket in most situations, here however we need to have multiple references internally (hence the shared_ptr).

Comment: @CodyGray These functions are intended to be used by a codebase that already has other memory management strategies in place (proprietary smart pointers) and we want to avoid additional confusion.

Comment: Do you want to keep the internal shared_ptr after you return? Or is the object mananaged outside since then.

Comment: @axalis The object is managed outside.  No internal reference is kept or needed.

Comment: @denver, then please edit your question, because it's nowhere clear what is the intended/wanted/real scope and lifetime of the shered_ptr you are referring to. That may make the difference between a formally correct answer but not appropriate for your scenario, and a correct answer appliable to your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for some reason you cannot/want not use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::auto_ptr` (for example if you need to have multiple owners internally during creation for some reason or your underlying methods require `std::shared_ptr` to be passed around), you can still make it work with `std::shared_ptr` by using custom deleter, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5995770/1274747

In the principle, after you're done before the return, you switch the deleter to not actually delete the instance (make the deleter "null") and then return by shared_ptr `get()`. Even after all shared_ptr objects are destroyed, the memory will not be deleted (as the nulled deleter will skip the deletion).

There is also a link in the comments not so well visible, which might be of your interest:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23866812/
(not sure though if it would really work without the shared ownership of the switch in all cases, would need to test)

---

#### EDIT

As expected, with the linked simple disarmable deleter from the pastebin you need to be careful, because the deleter is actually copied for storing in `std::shared_ptr`.

But you can still make it work by using `std::ref`:

```
MyFunc(MyObject*& obj)
{
    DisarmableDelete<MyObject> deleter;
    std::shared_ptr<MyObject> ptr(new MyObject(), std::ref(deleter));
    // do what is necessary to setup the object - protected by deleter
    // ...
    // disarm before return
    deleter._armed = false;
    obj = ptr.get();
    // deleter disarmed - object not freed
}
```

And just for completeness (and to avoid a potential future broken link), here is the implementation of `DisarmableDelete` from http://paste.ubuntu.com/23866812/.

```
template <typename T, typename Deleter = typename std::default_delete<T> >                                                                                                                              
    struct DisarmableDelete : private Deleter {                                                                                                                                                         
        void operator()(T* ptr) { if(_armed) Deleter::operator()(ptr); }                                                                                                                                
        bool _armed = true;                                                                                                                                                                             
    };
```

Comment: If you using shared_ptr - as the OP states - for "memory management," and then purposefully going out of your way to provide a 'null' deleter, then you're better off just using raw pointers with "new" in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but you still might want to auto-delete the object if something bad (e.g. exception) happens before you have everything done. Note that the deleter is not 'null' since the beginning, but you only make it 'null' after everything is fine and you actually want to return (and discard the ownership).

Comment: Thanks for following up with that example.

Comment: Why bother with `std::ref`, just `ptr.get_deleter()._armed = false;`?

Comment: Is the `_armed` accessible via `ptr.get_deleter()`? AFAIK the shared_ptr deleter is type-erased, so accessing `_armed` might involve casting (true, we know the type so we can `static_cast`).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on who "owns" the pointer, once it has been exposed to the 'outside world.'  Ownership essentially boils down to: "who is responsible for freeing this memory, later?"

It can be answered with a simple question: when `MyFunc` is called, is the *caller* responsible for deleting the pointer when it's done?

1. **If so**, then `MyFunc` needs to 'release' the ownership, otherwise the `shared_ptr` will automatically delete the pointer, when it goes out of scope.  This actually *can't* be done, using `shared_ptr`.  You need to use a `unique_ptr` instead, and call [unique_ptr::release()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/release/).
2. **If not** - if `MyFunc` will simply *use* the resulting pointer and forget about it without `delete`-ing it - then you can simply return the 'raw' pointer using [shared_ptr::get()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/get/).  You must be careful, because this implies that the `shared_ptr` still exists elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Won't returning shared_ptr::get() return an invalid pointer as the object would have been deleted when MyFunc ended and the shared_ptr went out of scope.

Comment: Not if the shared_ptr still exists somewhere else.  That's why you need to answer the question: who "owns" the pointer?

Comment: The caller assumes ownwership.

Comment: Then you can't use shared_ptr.  You have to use unique_ptr::release().  Or you have to change the API, so that the caller also provides a shared_ptr.  Or just use raw pointers with "new."

Comment: The OP specifically describe the use of the shared_ptr as "internal to the function", which may mean that its scope is limited to that function, thus it will call the deleter upon function exit, and the raw pointer will be a dangling pointer... boom

Comment: Uhm, from a more recent comment from the OP, it seems that the shared_ptr is "managed outside", still not clear what its scope and lifetime is...

Answer (score 3):

The point of `shared_ptr` is to express shared ownership.

Anything that does not share in the ownership of an object -- that doesn't have the right to make an object lifetime last longer, and the object lifetime is the union of the shared owners request for object lifetime -- should not use a `shared_ptr`.

Here, you have a `shared_ptr` and you are going to return it.  At that point, you are violating the assumptions of `shared_ptr`; anyone who kept a `shared_ptr` copy expects that its content can last as long as it requests.

Meanwhile, the calling code thinks it owns the `MyObject*` raw pointer you passed it.

This is an example of misuse of `shared_ptr`.

Saying "we have memory management issues, use `shared_ptr`" doesn't fix memory management issues.  Proper use of `shared_ptr` requires care and design, and the design must be that when the end of the lifetime of the object in question is shared by 2 or more pieces of data and/or code.

The internal code, if it does not own the pointer, should use either something like an `observer_ptr<T>` or a raw `T*` (the first to make it clear it doesn't own the object).

Ownership should be explicit, and in a `unique_ptr`.  It can then call `.release()` to pass ownership to a raw pointer if required; in practice, I would change your signature to take a `unique_ptr&`, or have it return a `unique_ptr`.

The caller would then call `.release()` when they want to use some other object lifetime management system, or that object lifetime management system should consume `unique_ptr`s (thus being extremely clear about taking ownership of things).

---

Use a non-hack solution.

Such as a `std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<T>>`.  In this case, you have shared ownership of a unique ownership.

The `unique_ptr` can have its ownership taken from it (via `.release()`).  When it does so, all of the `shared_ptr`s that still exist will have their `unique_ptr` also be cleared.

This places the shared unique ownership front and center, instead of hacking a non-deleter into a shared_ptr and having dangling shared_ptrs that think they have ownership over data but do not.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion.  The questions was about returning an object through an abstracted interface (application calling third party library).  There is no memory management issue and no shared ownership of the data across the interface, it is a situation of ownership being transferred.  One side is generating the data for the other side to consume.

Comment: This issue was about each side of the interface being able to manage memory in its own way.  A unique_ptr rather than a raw pointer would be an appropriate way to convey the relationship, but it is not an appropriate representation of the object's lifetime from the library's perspective, and a change in representation needs to occur to pass back through such an interface.

Comment: @denver The lifetime of an object is either managed or not.  If you have two systems both managing the lifetime of the same object, you have a broken design.  Unique ptr can actually give the lifetime of an object away (or, with a destroyer, have an arbitrary definition of what end of lifetime means).  Shared ptr fundamentally *cannot* do this; it is a type error to try.  You can hack it, but that is hacking around the design of shared ptr rather than using it properly.  Shared ptr by design does not play well with others; forcing it will result in bugs and code debt.

Comment: The caller cares not where the data came from or how it got created, from its perspective it is just getting it.  Similarly, the generator of the data should be able to manage it however is appropriate (in this case some sort of shared representation, as the object is assembled from multiple contributors) while it has ownership of it and not care how the caller manages it.    Also, unique_ptr (and other STL types) are generally not safe to pass across a library/application boundary as it may be defined differently on each side of the boundary, specifically if different compilers are used.

Comment: I understand the limitations of using shared_ptr internally from this perspective, and the question was really about how to get around it.  In this case, working around the limitation is looking more favorable then rolling out some sort of custom solution.

Comment: @denver No, "manage it however it wants" makes no sense. It needs manage so it can transfer ownership if it needs to transfer ownership. Transferring ownership is obviously not possible in *all* resource management systems (say, stack based). You have asked how to hack ownership transfer into a system that doesn't support ownership transfer. I am stating that your plan is a bad one, and you should solve it without hacking it in, and I pointed out problems with the obvious hacks. If your internal system is using shared ptr as a "generic smart pointer", that is your design problem.

Comment: @denver Added a concrete way to solve your problem without hacking around it.

Comment: std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<T>> is an interesting idea, although it may not be any clearer to code maintainers then the use of a custom deleter.

Answer (score 2):

I can see four alternatives, as highlighted below. They are all horrible, and short of switching your ownership to `std::unique_ptr<T>` and returning via `obj = ptr.release();` I can only offer a hack where the argument is assigned to the pointer upon destruction, but you still need to catch the exception and test whether the pointer was assigned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <exception>

struct foo {
  void bar() const { std::cout << this << " foo::bar()\n"; }
  ~foo() { std::cout << this << " deleted\n"; }
};

void f1(foo*& obj) {
  obj = new foo;
  // do stuff... if an exception is thrown before we return we are
  // left with a memory leak
}

void f2(foo*& obj) {
  auto holder = std::make_shared<foo>();
  // do stuff.. if an exception is thrown the pointer will be
  // correclty deleted.

  obj = holder.get(); // awesome, I have a raw pointer!
} // oops, the destructor gets called because holder went out of
  // scope... my pointer points to a deleted object.

void f3(foo*& obj) {
  auto holder = std::make_unique<foo>();
  // do stuff.. if an exception is thrown the pointer will be
  // correclty deleted.

  obj = holder.release(); // awesome, I have a raw pointer!
} // no problem whem holder goes out of scope because it does not own the pointer

void f4(foo*& obj) {
  // a super-weird hack that assigns obj upon deletion
  std::shared_ptr<foo> holder(new foo, [&obj](foo*& p){  obj = p; });
  throw std::exception();
} // no problem whem holder goes out of scope because it does not own
  // the pointer... but if an execption is throw we need to delete obj

int main() {

  foo* p1;
  f1(p1);
  p1->bar();

  foo* p2;
  f2(p2);
  // p2->bar(); // error

  foo* p3;
  f3(p3);
  p3->bar();

  foo* p4;
  try {
    f4(p4);
  } catch(...) {
    std::cout << "caught an exception... test whether p4 was assigned  it\n";
  }
  p4->bar(); // I still need to delete this thing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use internally `unique_ptr` and call its .release() method before returning the raw pointer.

If you are stuck to use shared_ptr internally, an option is to create it specifying a custom, "noop" deleter, that just does nothing when shared_ptr is destroyed (instead of calling delete on the owned pointer).  The get the raw pointer from `shared_ptr` as usual (.get() method). 
An example of such a deleter can be found in the Boost library ([null_deleter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/null_deleter.html)).
But please note that doing this effectively "disable" the usefulness of having a shared_ptr at all...

Comment: Cool, didn't know about `boost::null_deleter`. I checked it, unfortunately it might not be as useful in this case, as the OP apparently still wants to free the pointer if something happens before return, so what is needed would be a deleter which is not null at the beginning, but can be "made null" right before returning from the function.

Comment: @axalis than not a null_deleter, but the custom deleter approach is still valid, just need a more complex one that can switch between 2 behaviors (deleter => null deleter)

Comment: @roalz Thanks for helping to drive the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If your managing the lifespan of the allocated object internally with std::shared_ptr, and are returning a raw pointer for access and don't want this pointer to affect the ref count, you can return the raw pointer by calling shared_ptr.get().

It can be problematic to return smart pointers if your using a tool like Swig to generate wrappers for other languages.