# Convert std::shared_ptr into QPointer

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, qpointer

Our application is VERY poorly designed - it uses both `std::shared_ptr` and `QObject` parent-child relationship to manage some of our objects. This leads to segfaults when `QObject::~QObject` deletes its child objects and THEN `shared_ptr` tries to delete it also.

We discussed this but currently see no way to fix this easily so I'll need to use few dirty hacks until we fix it.

Now what I have is a `std::shared_ptr<MyObject> getMyObjectPtr()` function. I need to put the result into `QPointer<MyObject>` - QPointers are weak pointers that merely indicate if the QObject they manage is deleted. I cannot change that function in any way, it would break the whole application.

I tried few hacks with custom dealocator but that doesn't seem to work.

```
// get the shared_ptr from inacessible API
std::shared_ptr<MyObject> oldPtr(getMyObjectPtr());
// create a new pointer that never deletes it's value
std::shared_ptr<MyObject> newPtr(nullptr, [](MyObject*) {});
// Move pointer from old to new non-deleting ptr
newPtr.swap(oldPtr);
QPointer<MyObject> qptr(newPtr.get());
```

However this way, the pointer gets deleted once my function ends. Presumably, the custom dealocator moves along with the data.

Comment: Adding hacks upon hacks sounds like a great idea though

Comment: As far as I understand what you are trying to do is essentially trying to get your raw pointer and tell to `shared_ptr` that it is no longer responible for it, same as [`std::unique_ptr::release`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release), correct? AFAICT this is not possible - a `shared_ptr<T>` made with `std::make_shared` has the object itself allocated inside the control block, so it is impossible to get a "free", "normally"-deletable `T *` out of it. I'm afraid you'll have to fix your `getMyObjectPtr`.

Comment: If this instance of `shared_ptr` is actually a `unique_ptr` (meaning that it's not sharing the ownership with anyone), you might consider **moving** this `MyObject` instance from the ownership of `shared_ptr`. In this case, QPointer will point to *moved-to* instance, while `shared_ptr` will point to *moved-from* instance of `MyObject`. I might elaborate in the answer below, if that makes any sense for you at all.

Comment: @iehrlich: `QObject` doesn't support moving.

Comment: @MatteoItalia too bad :/ And I somehow guess that copy-constructing the underlying instance is not an option as well :)

Comment: @iehrlich: yep, `QObject` doesn't support copy as well; you *can* try to create a new underlying `QObject` in your copy or move constructor, but the resulting semantics will be extremely bizarre. The general idea behind `QObject` is that it [is an identity, not a value](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/object.html#identity-vs-value), so you are not expected to copy/move them around, as this would pose big problems about its relations to other `QObjects` (parent/son relationships and signal connections in particular; the "extra properties" and "object name" points in the linked page are less critical).

Comment: @MatteoItalia oh my... I mean, I've never used Qt in my life, and only commented considering *usual* C++ approaches *should* work :) Thanks for the tips anyways!

Comment: @iehrlich: of course, I was not criticizing the general approach, just pointing out why they cannot work in the situation OP is. :-) BTW, Qt is not a bad world - and IMHO it's definitely the only *serious* cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit around -, but you have to think more like Java or .NET (especially in the object model) than "modern" C++.

Comment: OP: does `getMyObjectPtr` return always the same object or it constructs a new one at each call?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833356/detach-a-pointer-from-a-shared-ptr

Comment: @ArneVogel `boost::shared_ptr` isn't the same as `std::shared_ptr`, right?

Comment: Designwise, it pretty much is. The evolutionary pathway is `boost::shared_ptr` 
 → `std::tr1::shared_ptr` → `std::shared_ptr`. And `std::shared_ptr` does not have `release()` or anything like that either.

Comment: @TomášZato: as I said above: does `getMyObjectPtr` return a `std::shared_ptr<MyObject>` pointing to an *existing* `MyObject` (i.e., the `shared_ptr` that is returned is *already* a shared instance) or it is some factory method, i.e. when you call `getMyObjectPtr` you receive a brand new `MyObject` wrapped into a `shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any good solution to this problem, other than to start refactoring your code so that any given object is either managed via QObject-style parent/child relationships, *or* shared_ptr<> reference counting -- but never both in the same object.  The two approaches are just too different from each other to easily reconcile.

That said, one thing that you might be able to do in order to accomplish the above without too much redesign is this:  instead of having a shared_ptr<> that points *to* your QObject, make the shared_ptr point to a (non-QObject-based), shared_ptr-managed sub-object of the QObject.

That is, instead of this:

```
class MyQObject : public QObject 
{
public:
   MyQObject(int x, int y, int z, QObject * parent)
      : QObject(parent), m_x, m_y, m_z {/* empty */}

   int getX() const {return m_x;}
   int getY() const {return m_y;}
   int getZ() const {return m_z;}

private:
   int m_x, m_y, m_z;
};

[...]

QObject * parent = new QObject;
shared_ptr<MyQObject> ptr(new MyQObject(1,2,3,parent));   // d'oh!  trouble!
```

do something like this:

```
class MyData
{
public:
   MyData(int x, int y, int z) : m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z)

   int getX() const {return m_x;}
   int getY() const {return m_y;}
   int getZ() const {return m_z;}

private:
   int m_x, m_y, m_z;
};

class MyQObject : public QObject
{
public:
   MyQObject(int x, int y, int z, QObject * parent)
      : QObject(parent), m_data(make_shared<MyData>(x,y,z)) {/* empty */}

   int getX() const {return m_data->getX();}
   int getY() const {return m_data->getY();}
   int getZ() const {return m_data->getZ();}

   shared_ptr<MyData> getData() {return m_data;}

private:
   shared_ptr<MyData> m_data;
};

[...]

QObject * parent = new QObject;
QObject * myObj = new MyQObject(1,2,3,parent));
shared_ptr<MyData> ptr(myObj->getData());   // no problem!
```

That way your Qt-style code has access to both the QObject and the MyData, while the shared_ptr-style code has access to the MyData.  (Of course, if your shared_ptr-style code needs also access to the QObject itself, you're probably out of luck, since Qt will decide when and where to delete the QObject and won't respect the shared_ptr semantics)